How to Implement Multi-Provider Authentication (Facebook, Google, Apple, Email) in React Native CLI for Android
Question:
I'm working on a React Native app using React Native CLI and trying to implement user authentication through Clerk. My goal is to enable users to log in with multiple providers: Facebook, Google, Apple, and email. However, I’m encountering some issues with the setup.
What I’ve Tried:
Configured Clerk for authentication and followed the setup documentation i believe.
Tried integrating Facebook, Google, Apple, and email authentication through Clerk.
Verified that my .env file is set up correctly with the necessary environment variables which when console.log showing what correctly.
Challenges:
The sign-up and login pages are not functioning as expected.
Despite following the documentation, the authentication flows are not working correctly.
I’ve used console.log extensively and confirmed that the .env file is configured properly, but something in the sign-up process isn’t working right.
What I’m Looking For:
Detailed guidance on integrating Clerk with multiple authentication providers in a React Native CLI project.
Troubleshooting tips for common issues with Clerk’s authentication setup.
Best practices for managing authentication state and error handling with Clerk.
Additional Information:
React Native version: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.75.2
Any assistance or insights on resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated!
essentially to get page to show

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

so i am trying to implement clerk on my project I am using react native cli
so when a user tries to sign up/sign in the clerk login appears and that usnt happening at the moment
